# Problems using ^ in calc

Tags: calc, keyboard, accessibility

I'm using calc on OSX and on a spanish keyboard, and I see some problems in using ^, but this is the most annoying:
when I type this example from de calc tutorial

```
 1:  2          2:  2          1:  8          2:  2          1:  6
     .          1:  3              .          1:  3              .
                    .                             .

    2 <RET>           3              ^              U              *
```

I always get:

Û is undefined on the minibuffer, what should I do, I can correct it with extra return pressing after ^, I need to press two time ^ in order to have it effect on calc

Comment: What keyboard layout have you set in your operating system and are you using any input methods in Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have composed characters (`^U` is composed to `Û`). That is usually already controlled by the OS.

Just hit the spacebar after typing `^` to get a caret as input character.